# getData doesn't work in Mage_Core_Block_Template custom block

Tags: magento

I defined a custom block this way:

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <categorylist module="mymodule">
                <file>mymodule.xml</file>
            </categorylist>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>

<global>
    <blocks>
      <categorylist>
    <class>Alias_CategoryList_Block</class>
      </categorylist>
  </blocks>
 </global>
```

Then I defined the block class this way

```
class Alias_CategoryList_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public $idCategory = NULL;

    // Contructor
    public function __construct()
{

        echo $this->getData('categoryid'); 
}
}
```

and the layout this way:

```
<default translate="label">
<block type="categorylist/list" name="categorylist.list" output="toHtml" after="-" template="mymodule.phtml"/>
```

I put the block in a CMS this way:

```
{{block type="categorylist/list" categoryid="10"}}
```

But sadly the $this->getData('categoryid');  retrieves nothing.
Cannot figure out what's wrong ?
I tryed even $this->getCategoryid; but even nothing.
Anyone can help?

I'm using Magento 1.7

Comment: I figured out that I can retrieve the value only if I declare in the class a public function _toHtml() and put the code in there..but after that the Html code in the phtml will not be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I assumed that the layout updates configuration will extend the code in the CMS but the code in the CMS should not have block name and template parameters for my purposes. So I fixed it declearing the template in the contructor and removing the layout updates in configuration (since I don't need the block to override existing blocks):

```
// Contructor
public function __construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('mymodule.xml'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be silly to add a view (phtml) template file that has

```
<?php echo $this->getCategoryId(); ?>
```

instead of trying to accomplish that in the constructor? Also then you wouldn't need your own code behind file you could just use `core/template`.

So your cms would be

```
{{block type="core/template" template="awesome.phtml" cateogryid="10"}}
```